# Performance overhead of standard containers and boost

Tags: c++, performance, boost, standard-library

[Adap.TV](http://adap.tv/) has chosen C++ to develop their software. However, they've decided not to use the standard containers<sup>1</sup> and boost for performance reasons, as they've blogged about it in the following article:

- [Why we use C++ (without using STL or boost)](http://engineering.adap.tv/2012/03/29/why-we-use-c-without-using-stl-or-boost/)

It says (emphasis mine),

> There are several rules that we are obeying **in order to keep the performance high**;
>   **Avoid malloc(), calloc() or new**
>   **No free() or delete** (and no need for tcmalloc)
>   **No STL, boost etc.**
>   Avoid locking as much as possible
>   # threads = # CPU cores (hyperthread is a trade-off between latency and throughput)

As we know, the standard containers use allocators which uses `new` and `delete` internally which are *expensive* operations. So to avoid them, AdapTv has avoided using standard containers altogether. Instead of using `new` and `delete` (repeatedly), they *reuse* memory (which implies they use a memory pool).

I'm wondering what's stopping them from using custom allocators for the standard containers! The custom allocator could use a memory pool internally which means *memory reuse*. So I don't see how standard containers would hurt performance.

Or am I missing something? Can't we avoid using `new` and `delete` with standard containers? Is there any other reason why would anyone avoid using standard containers? Or is it simply a lack of knowledge on their part which led to this decision?

And how about boost?

---

<sup>1) I suppose by *STL* they meant *C++ standard containers*, not [SGI's STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).</sup>

Comment: Boost I can see because some of the libraries can get pretty complicated, but nowadays there's no reason to avoid the STL, unless you're doing embedded programming I suppose.

Comment: When someone says to me that he does not want to use standard XYZ "for performance reasons", I translate this as "I love reinventing the wheel".

Comment: Can you point out ten differences between "reusing memory" and "rolling your own `malloc`"? I mean, lookaside lists are good and everything, but really, what else is there?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that new/delete are expensive (in comparison to what)? The standard allocators are relatively efficient in terms of re-using free'd memory you would be hard pressed to beat (pool allocators can help but I bet the performance increase is not as great as you think (and I would love to see a paper where they actually show this)). Otherwise I am going to have to believe this is a case of optimization based on myth and half truths.

Comment: I would like to see their performance metrics.  I too would like to see why they didn't use a pool allocator with the standard library containers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I cannot. I've not made those decisions.

Comment: @LokiAstari Allocating/releasing stuff on the heap is expensive by nature as it incurs calls to the OS with context switches. Your own pool allocator can be as simple as a few pointer assignments which is thousands of times faster, if not order of millions.

Comment: @LokiAstari: `new` can be expensive in comparison to other operations in C++. It is a system call, after all. Also, if something can be avoided to save some CPU cycles, should be avoided in a performance critical code.

Comment: @zxcdw: No true. There will be one call to the OS for every billion (exaggerated) call to new. The application gets pages at a time from the OS. Then manages those pages internally. That management of the pages is very efficient. So most of the time new/delete are efficient and basically involve swapping a few pointers.

Comment: @LokiAstari I can only take your word for that.

Comment: Reading the article I stopped when I got here: `It does not make sense to even try and compare C or C++ to Java`. This is just old school thinking. Java (with JIT) is now comparable to C++ (has been for quite a while).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Java is comparable to C++, in what sense? Only performance? How about memory? Does it not take too much of memory?

Comment: @Nawaz How much memory is "too much"? With mainstream smartphones sporting a gigabyte of RAM, I think it's a fair game to save development effort at the expense of a somewhat wasteful use of memory. Of course I do not mean that it's OK to be completely profligate with memory (perhaps, yet) but most of the time you can avoid this in Java anyway by following your common sense.

Comment: I've voted to close this as Not Constructive, as it is clear from the comments that even the underlying assumptions of the question are in dispute.  Perhaps you can encourage someone from the project (who presumably actually knows the answer) to answer the question?  As an aside, the article you linked seems pretty clear in its explanations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The explanations in the article are not convincing, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: @Nawaz: Hence my suggestion to Ask The Experts (pun intended).  The only way to know for sure is to profile their code, and you probably don't have it.

Comment: @Nawaz: I have no idea. But that emphasis my point. To think that is not even thinkable that Java is comparable is a silly point to start from. They are comparable and they should have done so. Personally I dislike Java (for other reasons) but if I was starting a new project from scratch and had the choice of languages (rare at the best of times) then I would have done some testing to see if they comparable and how they did for all metrics that were important. A blanket statement (without data) is worth less than a blanket.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty similar ruleset to what we used in my days as a C++ developer in the games industry (PS2/Gamecube/Xbox era). We had a hard rule of "no mallocs/frees in any code that was called every frame". Since they talk about "100,000s queries per second per server" I'm sure their goal is no mallocs/frees in any code that is called by every query.

Comment: Here's what astounds me. The problem with *all such recommendations* is they are flying blind, like a plane in the clouds with no instruments. Just having wings and a motor won't get you where you want to go, without guidance. Sure it might be that `new` & `delete` are costly, but just avoiding those won't make the code fast. You need to know how to *find out* what to fix. Sure - profile - everybody says. They say it, but they don't do it, and it doesn't work very well anyway. [*Here's what works.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `malloc()` and `free()` reuse memory, from the "pool" of your available RAM plus swap.  However, in the interest of making efficient use of resources, they make a number of trade offs for general purpose computing.  The [glibc source](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=70b9329cc3c38b6190baa707dc2daeefec32c982;hb=HEAD) and [this article](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) they reference discuss the trade offs in pretty good detail.

The most prominent trade off is time-space.  Essentially, if you want your allocator to be faster, you are going to end up wasting some space.  Pre-allocating a memory pool is an example of wasting space, since you have to allocate as much memory as you think you will ever need.  In a single-purpose computer like a server, that trade off is acceptable.  You're not going to want that memory for another application.

If you use STL custom allocators, you get control over where the memory comes from, but you still can't control when and how often the allocator is called.  Every once in a while, you unavoidably take a big hit, like needing to defragment.  You also usually need locking.  They are avoiding that problem altogether, at the expense of wasting some memory.  Wasting is probably the wrong word though, since it's a deliberate choice.  You're *investing* the memory to gain speed.

As a side note, it also happens to increase reliability.  I used to work somewhere with a prohibition on dynamically allocated memory, but not for performance reasons.  If all your memory is allocated at the beginning, you can easily determine your maximum memory requirements, and know a burst won't put you over your physical limit.

Comment: +1, as that indeed seems to be their approach: tying up large blocks of memory for personal consumption.